# PHP: pass global variable to finction?

Tags: php

There is code:

```
<?php
$pamiClient = new PamiClient($options);
$pamiClient->open();
$temp = 42;
$pamiClient->registerEventListener(

    function (EventMessage $event ) 
    {
        if ($event instanceof VarSetEvent) {
            if ($varName == 'CALLID') {
                $temp = 43;
                echo "Temp from CALLID: " , $temp, "\n";
            }

            if ($varName == 'BRIDGEPEER') {
                echo "Temp from BRIDGPEER: " , $temp, "\n";
            } 
        }  
    }
);

while(true) {
    $pamiClient->process();
    usleep(1000);
}

$pamiClient->close();
?>
```

How to pass $temp to function (EventMessage $event),  so changes are made in 
 `if ($varName == 'CALLID'){}` -section may be seen in `if ($varName == 'BRIDGEPEER') {}` section ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use global.

For example:

```
<?php

$varName = "foo";

function test() {
   global $varName;

   if ($varName == "foo") { ... }
}
```

Read more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 4):

You can [inherit variables from the parent scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) with `use`, for example:

```
function (EventMessage $event ) use ($temp)
{
   // to do something
}
```

Comment: For this usecase is this a better solution because you can trace back where the variable comes from.